# How to push records in git without pull ( for execution log maintenance, just append a file by multiple users on git)

Tags: git, github

I want to know how to push all the changes to git without pulling ( just append a file by multiple users)

The situation is I want to track all the execution history, so for that I created one python function which creates one CSV file where we are storing all the execution job information like name, machine name, job_execution_start_time, job_execution_end_time, job_status and all.

whenever any user executes the job then at the end of the script we are creating the CSV file for tracking. this file creating by multiple users, so we want at the last of our job execution all the records move from CSV file to git in append mode.

The reason is just track/maintain the execution history file on git, so that management can see the status of all the user's activity and status of jobs at one place.

Regards,
SG

Comment: *"push all the changes to git without pulling"* No way. Pull, change the file, add, commit and push — this is **the only** workflow in `git`. Either you need to follow it or avoid `git` at all. Use a database to append data after every run.

Comment: How is this csv file stored in git ? 1. Does each user append a line locally on their workstation, and push the csv file together with their commit ? 2. Do they push the file on a special separate branch ?